# Impossible to create my foreign key (1:n) error 1215

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I try to create a foreign key between tables users and roles (a user can have a role, a role can be given to several users)

I created first all my migrations, and then, I added a file with the foreign keys, to be sure that all tables exist.

The migrations :

[image]

Like you can, see the last migration is about foreign keys, this is the code :

```
class CreateForeignKeys extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');

            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('foreign_keys');
    }
}
```

This is the code of my user migration :

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nom', 45);
            $table->string('prenom', 45);
            $table->string('team', 45)->nullable();
            $table->string('tel1', 45)->nullable();
            $table->string('tel2', 45)->nullable();
            $table->string('username', 50)->nullable();
            $table->string('password', 50)->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('is_active');
            $table->dateTime('created')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('modified')->nullable();[![enter image description here][2]][2]
        });
    }
```

This is my database structure, like you can, I have the field "role_id", but not the key showing the foreign key and I have also this error :

And the error :

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: create table `roles` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(100) null, `description` varchar(255) null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

Tapez un message

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, please, show you roles table migration.

Comment: Are all tables empty? Otherwise there might be some corrupt data. Or the two fields between which you are trying to add a foreign key are not of the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
```

Make sure column type matches on `roles` table `id` like

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

Or change it to

```
$table->integer('role_id');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  To be completed, I had to write unsignedInteger because the role's id was in unsigned integer, all is working great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to establish relationships between tables and put a foreign key, u do not have to create a new table. Go to the model of the users

```
public function example()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(example::class,'insert foreign key);
    }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help.  Yes indeed, we have to insert this code into the model, but we have also to add code into the migration like Mike Ross said it.